# How to install old iWork on a MacBook with MacOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, pages, numbers, iwork

I have a new MacBook Pro running High Sierra (10.13.2) and installed current versions of Pages and Numbers. But I need also the old versions (from iWork 9 I think) with mail merge support. I had those installed in parallel on the former Mac also using MacOS 10.13 but that one is broken (main board failure).

Is there any official way to download the installer for iWork still running on current machines? I only found update packages on apple support so far.

Comment: If you have the HD from the dead Mac you could try moving the apps and support files over manually... Not sure if they work with HS tho...

Comment: @SteveChambers I tried that but Migration assistant did not work as the old filesystem was case sensitive and the new AFPS is not. Also copying the apps itself had troubles, maybe because of the same reason so I need a fresh install.

Comment: Do you have your original iWork install disc? Maybe starting from there would work...

Comment: @SolarMike that is a very good question, have to check that with a deeper look into my cupboards but my new MacBook no longer has a drive (and I have no external).

Comment: Got an older mac with a drive? Or a friend - can share the drive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found my original retail disc (thanks for the hint to [@Solar Mike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237687/solar-mike)) I installed from an external drive and upgraded with the package from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1563). Now I have again a working iWork 9.3, puh. Sometimes good to keep old installer disks.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you have any problem installing from cd in High Sierra?
Since Yosemite it says the new OS does not support installation of the old iWork 09.

My thinking is you have to (re)install Mavericks, install iWork from cd and then upgrade to Yosemite to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Cult of Mac has an article with a link to an [older Apple download of iWork trial for iWork](http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/iWork/Trial/2Z693-6764.01022009.awq23/iWork09Trial.dmg) which may work for you to use on your High Sierra. Give this a try and then let us know if you receive any complications with installing it.

https://www.cultofmac.com/306118/download-apples-iwork-apps-older-macs-free/

Comment: Thanks, but that article is about how to get the new pages etc on a older Mac. I have a brand new Mac with up to date Pages etc but additionally need the iWork 9.3 versions for some missing functionality.