# Need Mac Numbers & Pages for Mojave

Tags: macos, numbers, pages, iwork

I have a 2010 MacPro running Mojave. I've been trying to buy, copy, or steal copies of Pages and Numbers for hours just so I can work on a client's Pages file.

Why is this so hard?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the web version of Numbers and Pages on https://www.icloud.com.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309551/how-to-install-old-iwork-on-a-macbook-with-macos-high-sierra - idk if it's still viable & I can't test… as I did it a few years ago ;) Once you're registered as owning it in the App Store, you can then download the last version your Mac can run.

Answer (score 5):

Running on Mojave, a quick test of deleting Pages reveals that I cannot download the latest version from the App Store's main pages, but if I go to the list of "Purchased" apps in my Account, I can download a compatible version.

[image]

If you haven't already purchased (for the sum of 0) the iWork apps, then you likely can't download them on older OSes. It's well worth downloading them now, for the future!

Comment: Helpful if you need to download an older version that you previously purchased, which is my situation. Can't use this if you have never purchased before though.

Comment: Sadly, this no longer works since Big Sur (macOS 11)

Answer (score 2):

The web apps are quick and easy if you just need to work now.

- https://www.icloud.com/numbers
- https://www.icloud.com/pages

Answer (score 0):

An easy (non-Apple) way is to use Libre Office (I am using version 7.0.3.1). It opens Numbers spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "Why is this so hard?": Apple is not interested in supporting old OSes or computers that can't upgrade to the newest OSes. Apple's support best "effort" to "solve" this is saying "buy a new computer"

So you'll have to look somewhere. I found these versions that work with Mojave and High Sierra:

- Pages (working for Mojave): https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/pages/mac
- Numbers (working for Mojave) from: https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/numbers/mac

Comment: I know these are links that might go down at any time, but please, do not remove this answer. It might help people looking for these programs and save them all the time I wasted until I finally found this.

Answer (score -2):

Been to the app store, but tried one more time just to be sure. Here's what happens:

My Mojave is 10.14.6 and the app store won't sell apps to anyone running less than 10.15.x

All you get is an error message from the App Store, but the truth is out there if you hunt around enough.

I actually need Numbers more than Pages because my client put all the captions and sidebars in a Numbers spreadsheet. I no longer have working Microsoft applications, they died when I migrated to this 2010 MacPro. None  of my OpenOffice applications can pull off this trick.

Tried the iCloud approach, couldn't find a way to import the Numbers file.

I probably won't need Numbers or Pages very often after I get through this annoying project. I've been doing this stuff since Quark v.2 came out in the late 1980's, was a Compugraphic and Varityper typesetter before that. Onward!

Comment: If you drag the numbers file into the numbers web app, that often works. Worst case you have to upload it to iCloud. Sorry it wasn’t easy for you. Onward indeed!

Comment: Not sure this answers the question, it might make more sense as an edit to the question.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, since it solves nothing.

Answer (score -4):

Run the App Store application, search for Pages and Get it.  You will need to use your Apple ID, but there is nothing to pay.

Comment: Don't you thing everybody looking for information on this has already tried that? It doesn't work on old versions of macOS.