# running Numbers on Mojave

Tags: mojave, numbers

Several months ago I updated the OS of my MBP (early 2015) from Yosemite to Mojave 10.14.6. Numbers does not work any more. Tried to reinstall it from the App store but they say I need OS 10.15. In some [post here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407795/need-mac-numbers-pages-for-mojave) it is suggested updating from the "purchased" section of the App store. But Numbers does not show up there (Pages and Keynote do show up though).

Any suggestion (other then upgrading OS)?

Comment: "Does not work" how, exactly? Hangs, error messages, what?

Comment: Was the old install from the App Store? If so, check your purchased apps until you find it. If not (e.g. from iWork), you may be stuck. I suspect you can only 'buy' (for free) the current version which requires 10.15.  Depending on how you use Numbers, Libre Office may be the way to go.

Comment: @calum_b I get an error maessage "You can’t open the application “Numbers.app” because it may be damaged or incomplete.".

Comment: @Gilby the laptop came with Numbers already installed in it (same as Keynote and Pages). But Numbers  does not appear in App Store whereas Keynote and Pages do.  App store says  Keynote was "purchased" in  2018 and Pages on Sept 2020. Beats me. Maybe they mean I updated it then. Can't remember. So one cannot install a previous version of Numbers from somewhere? I found somewhere an iWork '09 package. Works but too outdated. Does not open recent .pages files. Dont know how to update it.

Comment: @Gilby: yes, LibreOffice works, but Numbers is nicer...

Comment: @GilBor "came with Numbers already installed". The would be an install using someone else's AppleID? Keynote "purchased in September 2018" means that was first date when your AppleID installed Keynote on any computer. The rights to install an App (and rights to newer versions) are tied to the AppleID - not the computer.  My guess is that you (using your AppleID) have never purchased (for free) and installed Numbers on any computer. If so, that leaves you without an obvious way forward.

Comment: @GilBor Yes, Numbers is nicer.  But at least LibreOffice provides a free way of doing spreadsheets.

Comment: @Gilby, Well, I dont know who installed Numbers on my laptop when it was new (I didnt), I bought it through a research grant and some service people in my workplace just gave it to me, ready to use, with all the basic programs working. Also, I dont know what is "AppleID" (sorry for the ignorance). Never mind. Now, if I upgrade the OS to 10.15 I can just install numbers from the App store for free, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store needs to find that your AppleID has "purchased" Numbers.  There are two ways to do this and they have already been covered in some detail in [Old version (macOS Sierra) for Pages, Keynote and Numbers, iWork](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376919/old-version-macos-sierra-for-pages-keynote-and-numbers-iwork)

Just needs a little adjustment for Yosemite rather than Sierra.

The way covered in detail is to install a pre-App Store version of Numbers and then the App Store will let you upgrade.

This is also described [here](https://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-get-iwork-apps-on-os-x-yosemite-for-free-on-older-macs/) and this is for Yosemite.

The second method is to install the current Numbers on another Mac (with macOS 10.15 or 11) using your App ID.  Then the App Store will then let you go backwards to an older version on your Yosemite Mac.

Comment: As I said in my question, my OS is Mojave, not Yosemite. But anyhow,  clicking through the links you provided,  I  downloaded from somewhere a nice working version of Numbers (version 6), w/o AppStore or AppleId or anything... Muchas gracias and greetings from Mexico!